# How to prevent go get from updating go.mod file

Tags: go, go-modules, go-get

> TL;DR: Is there any way I can forcefully prevent `go get` from altering the `go.mod` file?

When I do a `go get` of certain packages, e.g.:

```sh
$ go get github.com/AsynkronIT/protoactor-go/protobuf/protoc-gen-gograin
```

It will printout that it has updated dependencies (which are defined in my `go.mod` file):

```sh
go get: upgraded github.com/AsynkronIT/protoactor-go v0.0.0-20200815184336-b225d28383f2 => v0.0.0-20210405044454-10bc19881ad6
# (...) Note, this happens for other packages, not just `AsynkronIT/protoactor-go`.
```

This causes the `go.mod` file to change during a CI build, and affects subsequent build stages where, while building something, it’ll try to use an updated version of the dependency, which might introduce breaking changes, instead of the version defined on the `go.mod` file initially.

I’ve tried using `-mod=readonly` or making sure the `-u` flag is not used but it will still update the `go.mod` file, e.g.:

```sh
$ GOFLAGS=-mod=readonly go get github.com/AsynkronIT/protoactor-go/protobuf/protoc-gen-gograin

go get: upgraded github.com/AsynkronIT/protoactor-go v0.0.0-20200815184336-b225d28383f2 => v0.0.0-20210405044454-10bc19881ad6
# (...)
```

I've also tried finding similar issues, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23683359/how-to-avoid-updating-myself-with-go-get), or [this other one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674597/prevent-go-build-from-overwriting-version-in-go-mod), but haven't yet find an alternative to prevent `go get` commands from altering the `go.mod`.

The current workaround I'm using to stop this behavior is to do a `git checkout -- go.mod` right after certain `go get …` steps to reset any changes done by `go get`, and hence, avoiding breaking changes with certain dependencies newer versions.

I'm using go version `1.16.3`.

Comment: Have you considered/tried using `go install` with a version suffix? *"go install now accepts arguments with version suffixes (for example, go install example.com/cmd@v1.0.0). This causes go install to build and install packages in module-aware mode, ignoring the go.mod file in the current directory or any parent directory, if there is one. This is useful for installing executables without affecting the dependencies of the main module."* [1.16 Realse Notes](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#go-command).

Comment: The raison d‘etre of go get is to modify go.mod.

Comment: Can you perhaps describe why you want to get that specific package, and not store it as a dependency of your project ?

Comment: @Volker, if I got the question right, the OP was asking about why `go get` is updating versions of the dependencies. Ostensibly, the OP is puzzled about why not try to keep the dependencies at their current versions instead—if permitted by MVS, I fathom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Go 1.16 and after, you can use `go install` to install binaries without affecting `go.mod`

```sh
go install github.com/AsynkronIT/protoactor-go/protobuf/protoc-gen-gograin
```

Comment: Note, `@latest` or similar is required for this to work